# how to change proxy auth on ldplayer

Tags: python, android, adb

I have proxy "{host}:{port}:{username}:{password}".

I have run below  command adb but when I access internet, it still require enter username, password.

```
    os.system(f"adb -s {emulator} shell settings put global http_proxy {host}:{port}")
    os.system(f"adb -s {emulator} shell settings put global global_http_proxy_host {host}")
    os.system(f"adb -s {emulator} shell settings put global global_http_proxy_port {port}")
    os.system(f"adb -s {emulator} shell settings put global global_http_proxy_username {username}")
    os.system(f"adb -s {emulator} shell settings put global global_http_proxy_password {password}")
```

Does anyone have method to use proxy auth on ldplayer? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use oxy proxy Manager app. Easy to use and fast.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33838710)